# /etc/init.d/ssh restart does not reload the configuration

Tags: ssh, debian, sftp

I've added a chroot configuration to my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

I reload the configuration file using `/etc/init.d/ssh reload`, then try to connect using an SFTP client, but nothing changes, the user is able to log in but is not chrooted.

However, if I manually start an SSH daemon (on a different port) with `/usr/sbin/sshd -p2222`, the new configuration gets loaded and the chroot applies.

Any hint why `/etc/init.d/ssh reload` would not actually reload the configuration ?

Additional info:

- Same issue happens if I use `restart` instead
- While reloading/restarting, I have an open connection to the server for my root access
- I'm running Debian Wheezy.

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour if you make `stop` and then `start`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running `/etc/init.d/ssh restart` use `service ssh restart`.

On Ubuntu 14.04.2 the config changes will not occur when calling the init script directly. It's quite likely that Debian is the same here.

Comment: This answer sounded implausible to me, so I tested it on an Ubuntu 14.04.4 system. And it turns out this is indeed correct in the case of Ubuntu. I don't have a Debian system suitable for testing this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that neither `restart` or even `stop`+`start` was sufficient as it wouldn't kill the running daemon of sshd.

I had to grab a physical access to the server, stop, then `kill <sshd PID>` (so that the server wouldn't accept any new incoming connection), and then start again the daemon.

Comment: You could have done this remotely, killing the listening daemon doesn't touch running ssh sessions. That said, it sounds like you changed the pid file location in addition to other config changes, as I've never experienced having the ssh daemon not restarting.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about killing the daemon! I will try it out.